# Alternative function for MatLab iztrans to Octave?

Tags: matlab, z-transform, octave

I am trying to compute the reverse Z transform on Ocatve and I get the following error:

`error: 'iztrans' undefined near line 1, column 1`

The code I am running is the following:

```
syms z
F = z % Some function implementation
iztrans(F)
```

Comment: So, the Matlab docs for `iztrans` define the operation that `iztrans` is a shorthand for. I'm not versed with the symbolic analysis capabilities of octave, but couldn't you just implement exactly that?

Comment: Well what I am thinking is to use the definition of an inverse z-transform directly: [link](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/sasppt-150506134454-conversion-gate01/95/signal-system-inverse-ztransform-8-638.jpg?cb=1430919923) so I should define my problem as a contour integral. Trying the MatLab example ([link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/complex-line-integrals.html)) for contour integrals gives more errors in ocatve. ```error: quadcc: integrand F must return a single, real-valued vector```